# Custom mapper as jar file

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to write a custom mapper for Hive that is a jar file. How would I use this in my query?

Using the regular syntax:

```
add file myfile.jar

...

map using myfile.jar
```

doesn't seem to work. The error I get is:

> 2013-04-15 22:52:26,207 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator: The script did not consume all input data. This is considered as an error.
>   2013-04-15 22:52:26,207 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ScriptOperator: set hive.exec.script.allow.partial.consumption=true; to ignore it.
>   2013-04-15 22:52:26,207 FATAL ExecReducer: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Note: my jar is a jruby file compiled to a jar with [warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive will just execute any mapper script. In this case it needs to run the jar file like `java -jar myfile.jar` but it was trying to run it as `./myfile.jar`. My solution was to add a wrapper shell script called `myfile.sh`. The shell script ran the jar, and I used `myfile.sh` as the mapper. This way I was able to use a `.jar` file as a mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Hive uses 'streamable' custom mappers and reducers - a plain programs, that reads from stdin and writes in stdout. So usually there are script languages used for that: Python, Perl, PHP and even Bash. And Ruby, of course.

But if you want to use java program for that, you should to make that program executable. Do you really need to use Java for plain stdin/stdout work?

UPD: So instead JRuby just use plain Ruby.

Comment: I absolutely need to use java. Believe me this is not by choice. jRuby is not an option.

Comment: Can't comment your answer, so will answer here: I think wrapped .sh script is not solution. Hadoop reads mapper and reducer programs on master node and sends them to each node before execution. if you'll use wrapper, Hive/Hadoop will distribute only that wrapper, not wrapper&package.

Comment: It distributes both if you make it aware of both using `ADD FILE`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use exactly Java, try to write your own UDF instead mapper. Actually, HiveQL function and UDF's does same work as mapper.